# Need help installing php5.3.29 and apache2.2 in digital ocean ubuntu 14

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I want to install PHP 5.3.29 and Apache 2.2 in Digital Ocean Ubuntu 14, regardless of security issues. My problem is Ubuntu 14 is installing PHP 5.5.9 as default using `apt-get install`.

Can someone point me to the packages and libraries required to install PHP 5.3 and Apache 2.2 on Ubuntu 14?

Answer (score 0):

Even though php 5.3.x is obsolete, you can install it via the tutorial at this link: http://www.jabommi.de/wiki/downgrade-php-5-5-to-5-3-ubuntu-14-with-multiple-php-versions/

For apache 2.2 use the following apt-get command:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2=2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7 apache2.2-common=2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7 apache2.2-bin=2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7 apache2-mpm-worker=2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7
```

Comment: I have tried that tutorial. It is a outdated and didn't work for me

Comment: Did you get any specific errors when using these commands? We can help you out better if we know the exact errors you're facing.